# Compute complete graph and make minimum spanning tree

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'd like to plot a complete Graph and then compute the Minimum spanning tree of it. I already can make a complete graph out of a list that countrydata gives me:

```
centerCoordinates = CountryData["Asia", "CenterCoordinates"];
completeGraphAsia = 
 GraphPlot[Table[1, {centerCoordinates}, {centerCoordinates}], 
  Method -> "RandomEmbedding", VertexLabeling -> True]
```

I tried to make a minimum spanning tree out of it, but it didn't really work... obviously, because the Kruskal MST expects a graph variable, but I couldn't figure out how else to do it:

```
KruskalMST = MinimumSpanningTree[completeAsia];
```

Any help appreciated :)

Thank you!

Comment: Please try: `g = CompleteGraph[Length@centerCoordinates, VertexLabels -> "Name"]` and `FindSpanningTree[g, VertexLabels -> "Name"]`

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Wizard unfortunately those two commands crashes mathematica in my case.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard,,,I obviously spent too much time...but posted to illustrate relations between diffierent functions...remain disappointed with `GeoBackground`` issues which I have sent email to Wolfram about...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for illustration (and not dealing with distance or other edge weighting):

```
centerCoordinates = CountryData["Asia", "CenterCoordinates"];
asianames = CountryData["Asia", "Name"];
v = Length[centerCoordinates];
g = CompleteGraph[v, 
   VertexCoordinates -> (Reverse /@ centerCoordinates), 
   EdgeStyle -> Directive[LightGray, Opacity[0.2]], VertexSize -> 1];
st = FindSpanningTree[g, 
   VertexCoordinates -> (Reverse /@ centerCoordinates), 
   EdgeStyle -> Thick];
rules = Thread[Range[v] -> asianames];
hg = HighlightGraph[g, st, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick", 
  VertexLabels -> rules]
rcc = Thread[Range[v] -> (Reverse /@ centerCoordinates)];
GeoGraphics[{Red, Line /@ List @@@ (EdgeList[st] /. rcc)}, 
GeoRange -> EntityClass["Country", "Asia"]]
```

[image]